# Label name attribute is coming with + and quotes symbol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

While data coming from database to the view in grid the label name attribute is coming with + and quotes mark but I don't want that : below is my code which I am doing

```
@if (ViewBag.ExperienceDetailsGrid != null) 
{                                                                              
       var ExprowCount = 1;

       Foreach (var item in ViewBag.ExperienceDetailsGrid)
        {
          <tr class="data-contact-person1" id=@ExprowCount>
               <td><label name="Emp-name'+ @ExprowCount+'" class="Emp-name01">  @item.EmployerName  </label></td>

          </tr>
       ExprowCount++;
       }
    }
```

But the `label`'s `name` should be like this: `name="Emp-name1"`
but in browser debugger its coming something like this :`name="Emp-name'+1+'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily concatenate strings in razor like this. This should be what you are looking for:

```
<label name="Emp-name@(ExprowCount)" class="Emp-name01">  @item.EmployerName </label>
```